# Regex for float(x,y) possible?

Tags: html, regex, validation

In the following, `float(x,y)` means a number with `x` total **digits** and `y` decimals.

I am trying to do client side validation for an HTML Input field. The field corresponds to a MySQL column with data type `float(x,y)`. I know I can define a pattern like `float(5,2)` with lots of *'ORs'*. Is there an efficient way of generating a Regex for this such that I can encode it in my web document?

Something of a workaround is to specify `\d+(\.\d{1,y})?` and then set `maxlength=x+1`. Should be `x+1` because the decimal place is counted. This would then allow the *submit* of an integer of length `x+1` contrary to specification. I realize I can do JavaScript validation but I would like to achieve the desired with **HTML validation**.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Can't you use just `\d{5}\.\d{2}`?

Comment: Indeed, you forgot to mention what this regex should check besides the expression @PavelLint gave...

Comment: @PavelLint They say 5 _total_ digits, up to 2 can be decimals. So presumably 123.45, 1234.5, and 12345. should all match (and maybe 12345), but not 12345.6 or 12.345

Comment: You could do the length check with a lookahead: `^(?=.{8}$)[1-9][0-9]*\.(\d{1,2})$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXTLIf/4/)

Comment: "I realize I can do Javascript validation but I want to do it with HTML validation" can you elaborate? Why do you want to avoid javascript? My immediate response is "you can do this with javascript dude"

Comment: @JonasTuemandMøller I would prefer to exhaust the built in features with html before turning to Javascript. Anyways I am ultimately just going to do server side validation of the data once submitted. I have something that works reasonably well just with HTML already.

Comment: @Demo Thanks for the tip! I do not have much experience with lookaheads but I think ```(?=.{x+1})([0-9]{1,x})|([0-9]{0,x-1}\.[0-9]{1,y})``` is a solution

Comment: @CharlesDake small fix and I updated the answer. Since this is a floating point number, the first digit CAN be zero.

Comment: @jrook one think missing though in your answer is that it should match for ints without decimal points too. I didn't specify this clearly but it is valid in my usage.

Comment: @CharlesDake . *This then will allow the submission of an integer of length 'x+1' contrary to specification.* This implies ints without decimal points should not be allowed. I any case a simple int matching can be handled by adding `|^[1-9]\d{1,X-1}$` to the existing regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first check the total length with a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and then check for the length of numbers after the decimal point.

If you want **X** total number of digits and at most **Y** decimal points, you can use:

```
^(?=.{X+1}$)([1-9]\d*|0)\.\d{1,Y}$
```

Explanation:

```
^         asserts you are in the start position of the line
(?=       lookahead (zero length) match for:
    .{X + 1}     X+1 characters
    $            end of line //now you have asserted the total length
the whole part either
    0            is a single zero
    [1-9]\d*     more than a single digit and does not start with zero     
\.        a dot for the decimal point
\d{1,Y}   at least 1 and at most Y digits
$         asserts end of line
```

Note that you do not need to check the length of the whole part since you are already checking for the total length and the length of digits after the decimal so the part before the decimal point is automatically correct.

Example:

For `X = 5` and `Y = 2`, you will have:

```
^(?=.{8}$)([1-9]\d*|0)\.\d{1,2}$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXTLIf/8)